# How to use style in xaml to move an ellipse on canvas

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm practicing using xaml styles by making a simple traffic light controlled by radiobuttons. However, my code crashes because there is a reference error using Canvas.Top in the Ellipse style. Is there any way I could fix that while keeping everything in the style and not in the Ellipse itself?

Here is my code:

```
<Window x:Class="hw05.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:hw05"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Ellipse">
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Red"></Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>

                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=RedRB}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Red"></Setter>
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Canvas.Top" Duration="0:0:0.400" To="83">
                                </DoubleAnimation>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </DataTrigger>

                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=YellowRB}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Orange"></Setter>
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Canvas.Top" Duration="0:0:0.400" To="133">
                                </DoubleAnimation>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </DataTrigger>

                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=GreenRB}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Green"></Setter>
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Canvas.Top" Duration="0:0:0.400" To="183">
                                </DoubleAnimation>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </DataTrigger>

            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    
    <Canvas>
        <RadioButton Name="RedRB" GroupName="One" IsChecked="True" Canvas.Left="50" Canvas.Top="100">first</RadioButton>
        <RadioButton Name="YellowRB" GroupName="One" IsChecked="False" Canvas.Left="50" Canvas.Top="150">second</RadioButton>
        <RadioButton Name="GreenRB" GroupName="One" IsChecked="False" Canvas.Left="50" Canvas.Top="200">third</RadioButton>
        <Ellipse Name="Light" Width="50" Height="50" Canvas.Left="180"></Ellipse>
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

EDIT included setter for a Canvas.Top value and used parentheses for (Canvas.Top):

```
<Window x:Class="hw05.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:hw05"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Ellipse">
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Red"></Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=RedRB}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Red"></Setter>
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)" Duration="0:0:0.400" To="83">
                                </DoubleAnimation>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=YellowRB}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Orange"></Setter>
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)" Duration="0:0:0.400" To="133">
                                </DoubleAnimation>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=GreenRB}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Green"></Setter>
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)" Duration="0:0:0.400" To="183">
                                </DoubleAnimation>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    
    <Canvas>
        <RadioButton Name="RedRB" GroupName="One" IsChecked="True" Canvas.Left="50" Canvas.Top="100">first</RadioButton>
        <RadioButton Name="YellowRB" GroupName="One" IsChecked="False" Canvas.Left="50" Canvas.Top="150">second</RadioButton>
        <RadioButton Name="GreenRB" GroupName="One" IsChecked="False" Canvas.Left="50" Canvas.Top="200">third</RadioButton>
        <Ellipse Name="Light" Width="50" Height="50" Canvas.Left="180" Canvas.Top="82"></Ellipse>
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Canvas.Top` is an attached property so you should add parentheses around it:

```
Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)"
```

You should also set the `From` property of the `DoubleAnimation` to a valid `double` such as for example `0`:

```
<DoubleAnimation
    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)" Duration="0:0:0.400" From="0" To="133">
```

Alternatively, you could set the `Canvas.Top` property of the element being animated to an initial value:

```
<Ellipse Name="Light" Width="50" Height="50" Canvas.Top="10" Canvas.Left="180"></Ellipse>
```

Or add a `Setter` to the `Style`:

```
<Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="10"/>
```

Comment: It helped, but after adding parentheses (and a setter as Clemens commented) I'm still getting an inner exception error: "animation exception, cannot animate Top property "

Comment: @ŠamanBobo: See my edit. You also need to set the `From` property.

Comment: You are right, now I'm getting no errors. But it doesn't do what I wanted. I want the from to always be the current Canvas.Top value

Comment: @ŠamanBobo Then don't set the From property, but just an initial value, as shown in my answer.

Comment: @Clemens If I do that and set no From property, I'm getting the animation exception.
Is there a way I could bind the From property to current Canvas.Top value?

Comment: @ŠamanBobo: Not if you set the `Canvas.Top` property of the `Ellipse`.

Comment: @ŠamanBobo Please edit your question with what you are actually doing now. The code in my answer works.

Comment: I edited the question, with the code there I'm still getting an exception.

Comment: @ŠamanBobo: You haven't set the `Canvas.Top` property somewhere as far I can see.

Comment: After trying to set it in the Ellipse object there is no error anymore. Now, however, the ellipse only moves down, but doesn't move up.

Answer (score 1):

When you animate a property without setting the animation's `From` property, the animation starts from the current value of the property.

For `Canvas.Top` and the other Canvas attached properties, the default value (and hence the current value) is `double.NaN`, not `0`.

Just set an initial value by a Style Setter:

```
<Style TargetType="Ellipse">
    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="0"/>
    ...
</Style>
```

Or directly on the Ellipse:

```
<Ellipse Canvas.Top="0" .../>
```

You would also need to use the correct animated property path for attached properties, which uses parentheses:

```
<DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)" .../>
```